# Laravel 10, Model with 3 table, how?

Tags: php, model, migration, laravel-10

how can I solve it (Laravel 10) so that I can query all the rows and the corresponding "instrument_types" from the 3 tables via a model?

Database and Models:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuY26.png

I call it like this in my controller, but it's obviously not good:
`$hangszerek = Hangszer::all();`

I would like to receive such json data as a response:

````
  {
    "h_id": 1,
    "hangszer_nev": "Gitár",
    "brutto_ar": 100000,
    "kep_url": "https://image.com/image1.png",
    "cikkszam": "4792146AG",
    "leiras": "Nagyon fain gitár",
    "tipusok":[
      {
      "t_id":1,
      "tipus_nev":"Type 1"
      },
      {
      "t_id":2,
      "tipus_nev":"Type 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "h_id": 2,
    "hangszer_nev": "Dob",
    "brutto_ar": 120000,
    "kep_url": "https://image.com/image2.png",
    "cikkszam": "47924636BF",
    "leiras": "Nagyon fain dob",
    "tipusok":[
      {
      "t_id":2,
      "tipus_nev":"Type 2"
      },
      {
      "t_id":3,
      "tipus_nev":"Type 3"
      }
    ]
  }
]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need make a relationship many to many between your models read  [Eloquent: Relationships in laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) then you should make an Eloquent: API Resources to format json as response please read how to do it in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#main-content)